# javascript url multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having this current URL

```
"deviceSnapshots?1=1&deviceId=1&snapshotOf.ge=Sun%20Jan%2022%202017%2000%3A00%3A00%20GMT%2B0530%20(India%20Standard%20Time)&snapshotOf.le=Sat%20Jan%2028%202017%2023%3A59%3A59%20GMT%2B0530%20(India%20Standard%20Time)&order.by=snapshotOf"
```

i have this string in my url  `deviceId=1` where i have a single device.
what if i want to add one more device id say `deviceId=2`. how can i use both ids in same query string?

Comment: The question needs more details regarding how the URL is parsed/used. Maybe add a comma, and then parse the query again.

Comment: I'd change `deviceId` to `deviceIds=1,2`, so that you can split on the comma.

Comment: i tried using comma but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Typically you just specify the parameter twice like this:

```
deviceId=1&deviceId=2
```

Most frameworks will deserialize this URL as an array for you. Note however that this may lead to very long urls. In some cases it may be easier to use comma separated values or the like:

```
deviceId=1,2
```

but this means that you need to parse the string ("1,2") yourself.